# Woo commerce just like a product catalog

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to use a Woocommerce plugin for wordpress just like a catalog of products. The reason is, that now the client wants only catalog of products, but in future is possible, that he would like to sell product via website, so I would like to use woocommerce and then, just change some settings and the e-shop will work. Is that possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its very possible. The easiest way to do this is to create all of the products on WooCommerce as you normally would, and set no price for the products. If a product has no price, it will not be purchasable, but will still be displayed on the shop. It basically creates for you, a catalogue.

Once you're ready to sell the items, all you need to do is add a price.

Edit:

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );
```

You may also need to make changes to your css to hide certain things, it depends on your theme.

Comment: Of course, but there will be still things like cart, add to cart button etc? I found a plugin YITH woocommerce catalogue, seems it works OK

Comment: I've edited the question to include specific tweaks I've done on my own sites.